# How can I manually enable fisheye plugin

Tags: jira, atlassian-fisheye

I disabled some plugins to upgrade Jira. The upgrade was not carried out as new version of Jira needs 64 bit hardware.  Upon stopping and restarting the instance to resume with original application, I get this message:

```
The following plugins are required by JIRA, but have not been started:

FishEye Plugin (com.atlassian.jirafisheyeplugin)
```

catalina.out:

```
***********************************************************************************************************************
The following plugins are required by JIRA, but have not been started: FishEye Plugin (com.atlassian.jirafisheyeplugin)
***********************************************************************************************************************

2011-08-04 16:08:51,896 main FATAL      [atlassian.jira.upgrade.UpgradeLauncher] Skipping, JIRA is locked.
2011-08-04 16:08:51,896 main INFO      [atlassian.jira.scheduler.JiraSchedulerLauncher] JIRA Scheduler not started: JIR startup checklist failed.
2011-08-04 16:08:52,219 main FATAL      [jira.web.dispatcher.JiraWebworkActionDispatcher]

******************************************
JIRA startup failed, JIRA has been locked.
******************************************

Aug 4, 2011 4:08:52 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Aug 4, 2011 4:08:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 62989 ms
```

Does anyone have a clue as to how to re-enable fisheye plugin manually?

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks to all SO`ers.

Comment: Where are you seeing a requirement for 64-bit? If you're downloading the linux standalone variant, click on the show all link on the download page, and there is a 32-bit standalone version as well as a war/ear version.

Comment: Yes, I saw this after revisiting that page. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This also happens when the update is succesfull and you've deactivates FishEye before.  Sad.

There's an article in Atlassian's documentation at http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/How+to+Enable+the+FishEye+Plugin+from+the+Plugin+Administration+Screen, but this doesn't work for me (note that the plugin name is written wrong there, too).

Any other hints?

Comment: Hey Mathias. You are the man, my hero for the day. The fix worked on my end,  as you mentionned I just had to change the query to:

update propertystring set propertystring.propertyvalue = 'true' where propertystring.ID IN (select ID from propertyentry where propertyentry.PROPERTY_KEY = 'jira.plugin.state-.com.atlassian.jirafisheyeplugin');

Comment: Yes, surprisingly it worked for me the other day.  Maybe a typo while "correcting" the plugin name...